# Reading binary integers

Tags: c++, c++11

```
const unsigned char* p;
int64_t u = ...; // ??
```

What's the recommended way to read a 64-bit binary little endian integer from the 8 bytes pointed to by p?
On x64 a single machine instruction should do, but on big-endian hardware swaps are needed.
How does one do this both optimally and portably?

Carl's solution is good, portable enough but not optimal. This begs the question: why doesn't C/C++ provide a better and standardized way to do this? It's not an uncommon construct.

Comment: `int64_t` itself isn't portable. I have a feeling that even the most portable solution will have to make some assumptions (such as big- and little-endian are the only possibilities).

Comment: `int64_t` is standard C++11. It does assume the type is available though.

Comment: @XTF Exactly, that's what I mean. If the type is optionally available, then it's not portable. It's only portable among those systems that have a 64 bit type.

Comment: Couldn't he just do `int64_t u = *(int64_t *) p; u = le64toh(u);` ??

Comment: @sharth Simply put, no.

Comment: @H2CO3: Is there any five word followup you could give me? Is it a nonstandard addition that glibc and the bsds have added?

Comment: @sharth No, it simply misses the point. The point is portability and avoiding UB arising out of alignment mismatch. What you suggest disregards the endianness of the target machine and also introduces a potential misalignment error.

Comment: @H2CO3: The `toh` part is supposed to convert to whatever the host is. I do completely agree (and didn't think of) the alignment issues though.

Comment: Suppose endianness is not an issue: Would memcpy( static_cast< char* >( &u ), p, 8 ) be sufficient, or would it also run afoul of the aliasing/alignment rules?

Comment: @Andre : That's exactly the correct approach, though the `static_cast` is superfluous.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I don't know a portable definition of "portable". Thus, it is valid to say that "int64_t" is portable, because the standard sanctions its optional implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The commonly seen:

```
u = (int64_t)(((uint64_t)p[0] <<  0)
  + ((uint64_t)p[1] <<  8)
  + ((uint64_t)p[2] << 16)
  + ((uint64_t)p[3] << 24)
  + ((uint64_t)p[4] << 32)
  + ((uint64_t)p[5] << 40)
  + ((uint64_t)p[6] << 48)
  + ((uint64_t)p[7] << 56));
```

Is pretty much the only game in town for portability - it's otherwise tough to avoid potential alignment problems.

This answer does assume an 8-bit `char`.  If you might need to support different sized `char`s, you'll need a preprocessor definition that checks CHAR_BIT and does the right thing for each.

Comment: With my loop, a multiplication by `CHAR_BIT` does the trick, I believe :)

Comment: @H2CO3, yeah that will work - but the compiler is under no requirement to optimize/unroll that loop.  It'll probably work with most compilers, though.

Comment: @CarlNorum Eh, splitting hair... I'm not in the false belief that the compiler **will** unroll it, of course.

Comment: Oops -- my apologies -- I missed the statement that the data was little-endian.

Comment: @JerryCoffin No worries. Same thing happened to me today.

Comment: If you `and` each byte with `0xFF`, the above will work even on machines where `char` isn't 8 bits.  And it will also work on machines where `char` is signed, which the above doesn't.

Comment: @James - the `p` is explicitly `unsigned` in the OP's post.  And anding with `0xFF` won't fix anything about `char` longer than 8 bits.

Comment: @CarlNorum So it is.  But anding with `0xFF` _will_ still fix the char longer than 8 bits issue.

Comment: @James, how? If `CHAR_BIT` is greater than 8, anding with `0xff` will just throw away data.

Comment: @CarlNorum It will throw away data that should be thrown away.  Where does the input buffer come from?  If you've read it from somewhere, say the internet, only the lower 8 bits will be significant.  You're right that if the input format specifies 9 bit characters, then you shouldn't and with `0xFF`.  But none do, because if the input format specifies 9 bit bytes, it can't be read on a machine with less than 9 bit chars (or reading it will be a Herculian task).

Comment: @CarlNorum Of course, if he has `int64_t`, the size of his char must be 8, 16, 32 or 64.  It's true that if char is more than 8 bits there, then you won't want to and with `0xFF` (and you won't want to loop 8 times, either).  I was thinking of the older, 9 bit machines when I wrote the above (but of course they wouldn't have `uint64_t`); maybe today, it would be more portable to loop `sizeof(uint32_t)` times, shifting `CHAR_BIT * n` each time.  I have heard that there are modern machines with 32 bit char's, where as I think the last machine with 9 bit chars went out of production recently.

Answer (score 4):

Carl Norum is right - if you want to be readable as well, you can write a loop (the compiler will unroll it anyway). This will also nicely deal with non-8-bit `char`s.

```
u = 0;
const int n = 64 / CHAR_BIT + !!(64 % CHAR_BIT);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    u += (uint64_t)p[i] << (i * CHAR_BIT);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it only loop 4 times if CHAR_BIT = 16?

Comment: @XTF This will loop only 4 times if `CHAR_BIT == 16`, since `64 / 16 + !!(64 % 16) = 4 + !!0 = 4 + 0 = 4`.

Comment: If `CHAR_BIT` is `9` (parity bit), then your reads will either fall short or read too far.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Why? It will then read 8 bytes (72 bits). What's the problem with that? If there's truly a 64-bit integer in the original data, the 8 most significant bits should be zero in the original representation, I assume.

Comment: @H2CO3: you are making an assumption here, that 72 bits will have been written to the source you are reading from. This is only true if the source *also* used 9 bits a byte. Since the assumption is that the source may have a different byte order than the current process, why should it have the same `CHAR_BIT` ? And if it does not, then there may only have been 64 bits written where you are trying to read 72. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I assume that the source and the destination are on the same machine, since they are in the very same program. Am I missing something?

Comment: @H2CO3: I just read *64-bit binary little endian integer* without any notion of where it's coming from. If it were coming from the same machine then why would the endianness be different ? Anyway, 64 bits seems to mean 64 bits, not 72.

Comment: @MatthieuM. But you can't represent 64 bit on a machine with 9-bit chars. You can either represent 63 or 72. And since 63 is not enough...

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to reverse the byte order for any variable. I used it to convert between different "Endianess".

```
// Reverses the order of bytes in the specified data
void ReverseBytes(LPBYTE pData, int nSize)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = nSize - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        BYTE nTemp = pData[i];
        pData[i] = pData[j];
        pData[j] = nTemp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's bad, you shouldn't modify your input.

Comment: No, it's not bad. Why would you suggest such an arbitrary rule? I've been doing this an awfully long time. It depends entirely on your needs.

Comment: The rule is not arbitrary. `ReverseBytes` is not itself the problem; the caller of such a routine likely expects the data pointed to to be reversed. The problem is that if one uses `ReverseBytes` in a routine to convert little-endian data to a native integer, the caller of that routine likely does not expect the input data to be changed. So you are doing something unexpected that can cause a bug.

Comment: Are you guys serious? I'm showing how to do what the OP asked about. I am not new to this. I'm using this in a real-world application and I have *never* had a problem such as being described. And if you think it could be a problem for your particular application, then modify it to make a copy for heaven's sake. I find the objection to be trivial, and incorrect when stated as an absolute.

Comment: You've only posted a swap function, you haven't shown how it'd be used to solve the actual problem.

Comment: @XTF: "That's bad, you shouldn't modify your input": says who? the standard libs do it, too. Sometimes, it's what is needed, even though often, it is not. It depends.